# Select from the Results of Unpivot Transform:SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, unpivot

I have an excel file with some columns as shown below. 
[image]

I am using it as Excel Source in SSIS package. 
I have Unpivotted the columns 2012, 2013 and 2014 using Unpivot Transform whose results look like

[image]

How can I send the output of this Unpivot Transform out of its data flow and Excecute SQL Task on it or send it to another Data Flow in the same package for various transformations? I do not want to use the option of writing the output of Unpivot Transform into OLEDB Destination and then Read them Back.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute an SQL query on the Excel data, you can do this inside the DataFlow Task using an `OLEDB Command transformation` *(The OLE DB Command transformation runs an SQL statement for each row in a data flow.)*

Or you can use a `RecordSet Destination` to store data in a In-Memory Table (Table variable) and use it outside the DataFlow Task

You can follow the following links to learn more:

- [SSIS OLE DB Command Transformation](http://www.excoded.com/learn/ssis/ssis_oledbcommand.php)
- [Microsoft Docs - OLE DB Command Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation)
- [Use a Recordset Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/use-a-recordset-destination)